# Is Ahsoka considered a Jedi during the Imperial period?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, star-wars-rebels

Another question I asked led me to realise this seems yet to be addressed. We know that Ahsoka is not a Jedi de jure. However, is she considered to be a Jedi de facto?

At the point when she officially left the Jedi Order, she was vindicated of the crimes against the Jedi she was accused of, and was in fact offered a return into the Order. That means she is eligible to become a Jedi again if she so chooses, and the Jedi Council considers her worthy to be called a Jedi again.

However, she rejected the offer because she lost faith in the Order. She chose to "find her own way", which suggests she no longer fully agree with the Jedi ways *as interpreted by the Jedi of the Late Republic*.

Yet, one can also argue that the Jedi Order of the late Republic has grown arrogant and strayed from the *true* Jedi ways. In more ways than one, the Jedi of the late Republic can be said to be not how a true Jedi should be. This has been argued to death for years and can be considered to be largely true.

During the Imperial period, Ahsoka returned to embrace her Jedi heritage again at its purest roots, serving as a protector of the galaxy and its people against the Empire as best as she can. She has been known to actively involve herself in "Jedi business", protecting the interests of the future of the Jedi such as Force-sensitive children.

However, even though Ahsoka is actively attempting to prevent the complete extermination of the Jedi Order for good, we do not know her own philosophy of the Force, and how they align with the official Jedi philosophy. We know only that she is opposed to the dark side. This only ensures she is a pro-Jedi ex-Jedi, but this doesn't necessarily mean she is no different in her beliefs from a Jedi who never left the Order.

Considering the various points above (and others I may have missed), is Ahsoka a Jedi de facto?

Comment: She's a known rebel. I guess that means that she'd be considered a Jedi by the Empire.

Comment: This is why I coined the term "quasi-Jedi" :)

Comment: Is there anyway I can improve my answer?

Answer (score 4):

### No, she is not.

In the *Rebels* episode *[Shroud of Darkness](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shroud_of_Darkness)*, Ahsoka states that she no longer considers herself a Jedi.

> Because I am no longer a Jedi. It was my choice, I left the Order.

She says the same thing in *[Twilight of the Apprentice](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Twilight_of_the_Apprentice)*.

> I am no Jedi.

Comment: I wonder what she considers herself as then. Definitely a friend of the Jedi. Seeing as how we have Dark Jedi...Maybe she is a Light Sith?

Comment: @thegreatjedi Definitely not, she makes it very clear that she completely disagrees with the Sith multiple times.

Comment: she also references her not being a Jedi in "The Future of the Force" -- 
"Kanan: What I have to say is Jedi business. Ezra: Then I guess I qualify. Ahsoka: You qualify more than I do." - http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=star-wars-rebels-2014&episode=s02e08

Answer (score 1):

I think she passed her great trial, so was a Jedi, before she left the order.

As to the rest of your question I suppose it depends on your point of view as to what a Jedi is. Was being a Jedi defined by a certain level of competence in certain ways of the force and following a moral code, or belonging to a (defunct) organization.

As Luke became a Jedi after passing his great trial, with no Jedi order, and nobody left to ordain him. I believe it is the former definition, but I think it is arguable either way.

The late Republic Jedi way failed. Ashoka perhaps represents the start of a new interpretation of the Jedi way.

The same sort of thing happens in religions. Some people feel that a religious organization has strayed from it's ideals so go of and do their own thing which is more in tune with what they thing the right way is. It is difficult for an outsider to judge which one is correct.

Comment: HAHA!! She is a Jedi Ortodox!!